# How to return promise object as array of strings?

Tags: javascript, promise, cheerio

I have the following code

```js
const link =
  "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/ireland?location=dublin&location=dublin-city&sort=publishDateDesc";

async function getLinks(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((html) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const sel = '[data-testid="results"] a[href]';
      var links = [...$(sel)].map((e) => e.attribs.href);
      return Promise.all(links);
    });
}

getLinks(link).then(function(links) {
  console.log(links);
});
```

This  returns me an object array like this

```
[
  '/for-rent/apartment-105-cabra-road-phibsborough-dublin-7/4071977',
  '/for-rent/apartment-weavers-hall-leopardstown-dublin-18/4073220',
]
```

I would like this to be returned as array of strings so I can perform comparison operations more easily and so I can store the array in a variable.

Also I want know how to use `await` in this

I want it to work like this but it fails currently

```
const a = await getLinks(link1);
const b = await getLinks(link2);
```

where `a` and `b` contain string arrays.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you'll need to use the first link's domain name?

Comment: @kelly I didn't understand what you meant, did you mean ```link1``` and ```link2``` and similar domain? if yes, then yes.

Comment: `Promise.all(links);` isn't necessary--there's no promise there. `async` isn't needed here either since you're not using `await` inside `getLinks`. Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand the problem. You already have an array of strings and sure, you can call the function as many times as you want with different URLs. What does "this fails" mean? Did you get an error there?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `await` unless it is within an `async` context. It's like calling `then` on a non-Promise object. You could wrap it within an anonymous async method such as:

```
(async () => {
  const a = await getLinks(link1);
  const b = await getLinks(link2);
  // do something
})()
```

...or using Promise.all:

```
(async () => {
  const [a, b] = await Promise.all([getLinks(link1), getLinks(link2)]);
  // do something
})()
```

It is also strongly recommended and a best practice to wrap `await` usage within a `try...catch` block in case the Promise fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first part of the URL with the built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) api:

```js
const link = "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/ireland?location=dublin&location=dublin-city&sort=publishDateDesc";
  
const url = new URL(link);

console.log(url.protocol + "//" + url.host);
```

Then you can append the links you get to this:

```
const url = new URL(link);

const a = await getLinks(url.protocol + "//" + url.host + link1);
const b = await getLinks(url.protocol + "//" + url.host + link2);
```

---

If you want to use `await` at the top level, and if the environment doesn't support [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await), then yes you'll have to create an async IIFE:

```
(async () => {
    // your code
})();
```